# Flink jdbc sink not commiting in web ui

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a problem with one of my new developed flink jobs.

When i run it in IntelliJ the job is working fine and commiting records to the database.

Next step was to upload it to the flink web ui and execute it there.

The database connection is established and also the inserts seem to be sended to the oracle database but the data seems to be not commited.

Im using a DataStream with the following setup:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.enableCheckpointing(10000);
...
DataStreamSink<POJO> pojoSink = filteredStream
.addSink(JdbcSink.sink(
sqlString,
JdbcStatementBuilder,
new JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()
                                        .withUrl(url)
                                        .withDriverName(driver)
                                        .withUsername(user)
                                        .withPassword(password)
                                        .build());
```

I have no clue why it works on my laptop in the IDE but not on at the server via the web ui.
The server logs are also not having any errors and showing the checkpoints.

Maybe someone has a suggestion where i can have a look what the problem might be.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was a one time error. At the next time the job run perfectly.